# Get classpath for gradle project using Android plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've been building some tasks for a gradle multi-project build and have a need to get the class path for a project.  The build script has projects that use the Java plugin and projects that use the Android plugin.

For the Java projects I was able to use the top voted answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106565/how-do-i-generate-the-class-path-for-a-gradle-project)  to get the class path using `configurations.runtime.asPath`; however, this is not working for the Android projects because there is no configurations.runtime property.

How can generate a classpath for a gradle project using the Android plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Android projects may build multiple versions of the app.  These are called variants.  The most basic variants are "debug" and "release"  The following code should create the classpath assignment for all the variants in a project.  Place this code in the "build.gradle" file for the module.

```
android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
    variant.javaCompile.classpath += configurations.provided
}
```

You should be able to refer to a specific variant using the variant name:

```
debug.javaCompile.classpath
```

Comment: I got diverted off this path but I'm trying to clean up old questions.  How would take what you've written and echo the classpath to the screen?  Is `debug.javaCompile.classpath` now something that can be used directly from task code?

Comment: @SteveMitcham nope you need to parse variants as done here in butter knife https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/574ed28042dc30c14a623f0d36e666ff8008d32c/butterknife-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/butterknife/plugin/ButterKnifePlugin.kt#L22

Answer (score 2):

Here is a gradle task that generates the module jar and includes also the test classpath for all variants.
It is including libraries and the android.jar from selected runtime.

I've added two commandline executions for updating some env var inside emacs and for killing any running beanshell (with previous classpath).

```
task classpath(type: Jar) {
  from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs,
       android.sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs
  outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
  doLast {
    println "Building classpath..."
    def cp2 = [android.getBootClasspath()[0], it.archivePath]
    android.applicationVariants.all { v ->
      cp2 += v.getApkLibraries()
    }
    def classpath = cp2.unique().join(":")
    println "Updating emacs..."
    exec {
      executable "sh"
      args "-c", "emacsclient --eval '(setenv \"CLASSPATH\" \""+classpath+"\")'"
    }
    exec {
      executable "sh"
      args "-c", "emacsclient --eval '(jdee-bsh-exit)'"
    }
  }
}
```

Be aware that I'm using ":" for joining the classpath

Comment: It looks like getApkLibraries() doesn't exist anymore. You don't happen to have an updated version of this code?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I'm not using this integration anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
project.android.applicationVariants.all { v ->
            v.getCompileClasspath(null).getFiles().each{
                File f->
                    f.getAbsolutePath()//this is the one of classpath
            }
        }
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example a gradle task that generates javadocs with umlgraph + graphiz in an android project and includes classpath for all variants using the coding example given in the user1737310's previous answer. It is manually including android.jar from the selected runtime, I am still looking for a way to retrieve it dynamically.

```
    task javadoc(dependsOn: build) {
    setDescription('Generates Javadoc API documentation with UMLGraph diagrams')
    setGroup(JavaBasePlugin.DOCUMENTATION_GROUP)

    doLast {
        def javaFilePath = file('src/main/java')
        def cp = [System.getenv('ANDROID_HOME')+'/platforms/android-26/android.jar'];
        project.android.applicationVariants.all { v ->
            v.getCompileClasspath(null).getFiles().each{
                File f->
                    cp.add(f.getAbsolutePath())//this is the one of classpath
            }
        }
        def classpath = ":"+cp.join(':')
        if (javaFilePath.exists()) {
            ant.javadoc(classpath: (configurations.umljavadoc).asPath + classpath, 
                        sourcepath: file('src/main/java'), 
                        packagenames: '*',
                        destdir: "${docsDir}/javadoc",
                        private: 'false',
                        docletpath: configurations.umljavadoc.asPath) {
                doclet(name: 'org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc') {
                    param(name: '-inferrel')
                    param(name: '-inferdep')
                    param(name: '-qualify')
                    param(name: '-postfixpackage')
                    param(name: '-hide', value: 'java.*')
                    param(name: '-collpackages', value: 'java.util.*')
                    param(name: '-nodefontsize', value: '9')
                    param(name: '-nodefontpackagesize', value: '7')
                    param(name: '-link', value: 'http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/spec')
                    param(name: '-link', value: 'http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/docs/api')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`