# Get classpath of Android project in gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build

I'm writing a gradle task, which should execute a java application, but I can't get the classpath of my Android project.

My gradle task:

```
task helloWorld(type: JavaExec) {
  classpath = buildscript.configurations.classpath;
  main = "com.test.HelloWorld";
}
```

This doesn't work.

How can I get the classpath (which includes all classes and dependencies)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get classpath for gradle project using Android plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222747/get-classpath-for-gradle-project-using-android-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution the source folders and the libraries.
But I still miss the android.jar.
There Is another question for this problem: [Finding android.jar for a own written Java task (in gradle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076181/finding-android-jar-for-a-own-written-java-task-in-gradle)

```
class JavaTask extends JavaExec {    
    @Override
    void exec() {
        List<String> classpaths = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getClasspath().getAsPath().split(";")));

        project.android.libraryVariants.all  { variant ->
            classpaths.add(variant.javaCompile.destinationDir.getPath());
        }

        org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration config = project.configurations.getByName("compile");
        for (String path : config.getAsPath().split(";")) {
            classpaths.add(path);
        }

        setClasspath(project.files(classpaths.toArray(new String[classpaths.size()])));
        super.exec();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the second answer of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40515402/3130610

It does the trick.